# How to map json key to a class property

Tags: c#, json

I have a json response like below

```
{
  "Robert": [
  {
    "id": "123",
    "class": "7th",
    "lastname": "johnson"
   }
 ],
 "William": [
  {
    "id": "124",
    "class": "7th",
    "lastname": "parker"
  }
 ]
}
```

i want to map it to c# class. 
Using online converter i get below structure

```
public class Robert {
 public string id { get; set; }
 public string class { get; set; }
 public string lastname { get; set; }

}
public class William {
 public string id { get; set; }
 public string class { get; set; }
 public string lastname { get; set; }

}
public class Application {
 public IList<Robert> Robert { get; set; }
 public IList<William> William { get; set; }

}
```

instead i would like to map the student name as one of the class property say .. "Name"

```
public class Student{
 public string Name{ get; set; } //Robert is mapped to this 
 public string id { get; set; }
 public string class { get; set; }
 public string lastname { get; set; }

}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Your JSON looks like perverted attempt to serialize a collection, and the "class" isn't a problem here. Is this JSON something you can control?

Comment: If you use newtonsoft you can add the [JsonProperty("xyz")] attribute to your class properties. Just replace the "xyz" with the corresponding json key.

Comment: Use a dictionary of lists: `public class Application { public Dictionary<string, List<Person>> Persons { get; set; } }` where `Person` is just your renamed Robert/William class. The key of the dictionary will be the given name (Robert, William) the value will be a list.

Comment: If using Newtonsoft Json, you can always create a JsonConverter for your structure. Then you have full control of how it is Serialized and Deserialized. Just an option to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } //Robert is mapped to this 
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("class")]
        public string _class { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var responseStream = @"{""Robert"": [{""id"": ""123"",""class"": ""7th"",""lastname"": ""johnson""}],""William"": [{""id"": ""123"",""class"": ""7th"",""lastname"": ""johnson""}]}";
        var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseStream); //Deserialized JSON to type of JObject
        var list = responseObject.Properties();
        var students = new List<Student>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var s = responseObject[item.Name].ToObject<List<Student>>();
            s.ForEach(x => x.Name = item.Name);
            students.AddRange(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read above JSON like this

```
var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseStream); //Deserialized JSON to type of JObject
var robert = responseObject["Robert"].ToObject<Student>();
```

your student class should be like this

```
public class Student{ 
 public string id { get; set; }
 public string class { get; set; }
 public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```

with this, you can read the id, class, lastname of Robert.

just an option to read JSON responses like yours.

Answer (score 0):

`Deserialize` the json to `Dictionary<string, List<Student>>` and use `Linq` to convert to the desired object

```
var strJSON = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var objStudents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Student>>>(strJSON);
var result = objStudents.Select(x => new Student
{
    Name = x.Key,
    id = x.Value[0].id,
    studentclass = x.Value[0].studentclass,
    lastname = x.Value[0].lastname,
}).ToList();
```